# Como usar GIT conectado no servidor?

Tags: git, ftp, deploy

Estive procurando a algum tempo sobre como eu poderia substituir o meu `filezilla` e recebi algumas respostas de que é possivel usar o git como um intermédio para que eu possa rodar meu site/projeto de acordo com o que está no tal repositório.

Encontrei também um [artigo sobre o `DeployBot` no `tableless`](http://tableless.com.br/deploybot-faz-o-build-e-deploy-do-seu-projeto-para-producao/), porem não consegui entender muito bem qual a definição de deploy e utilização de tal ferramenta! existe alguma maneira de conectar um repositório com um servidor e abandonar de vez o cliente FTP?

Comment: Dica: se você entende de inglês, te recomendo fortemente nesse curso de GIT: https://www.codeschool.com/courses/try-git e enquanto deploy é bem complicado, tudo depende do projeto, comecei com Capistrano que é ótimo para Ruby on Rails.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sim, e você deve fazer isso, abandone de vez o FTP.

Mas a pergunta principal deve ser, e como é que se faz?

O Git é uma ferramenta de SCM (Source Control Management), ou seja, uma ferramenta para o controle do seu código, versionamento, tag, histórico e tudo de mais legal que esse tipo de ferramenta pode entregar, por legal quero dizer essencial, faça o uso dela, viver com o perigo de perder o código e não ter onde buscar depois é uma loucura, sem contar outros pontos. Não irei me aprofundar sobre isso, pois poderia levantar inúmeros motivos pra utiliza-lo.

Mas somente a utilização do SCM não resolve completamente o seu problema de utilização de FTP pra fazer o deploy. Sim, deploy, você já faz esse processo sem conhecer o termo. Não é nada além de você subir as suas alterações para o seu servidor, no momento que você fez isso, você acabou de fazer um deploy. Mas esse é um processo muito chato quando manual, não? Sim, é chato e sempre igual, por isso existem muitas ferramentas pra fazer isso de forma automatizada pra você, servidores de integração continua que sobem suas alterações para você, e isso é ótimo, pois você será muito mais rápido no seu desenvolvimento e irá parar de perder tempo com tarefas repetíveis e propensas a erros.

Mas isso é um assunto realmente grande, passei bem por cima e não ensinei com um hands-on, somente teoria superficial. Por isso recomendo você ler sobre Integração Continua, e como implementar. Isso com certeza vai mudar o seu processo de desenvolvimento, claro, para muito melhor.

Comment: Entendi perfeitamente o que você disse, porém gostaria de referencias de como usar o sistema git para enviar os arquivos para o servidor entende?

Comment: Qual o stack de tecnologia que você utiliza?

Java, Javascript, PHP, Python...

Comment: Uso apenas PHP.

Comment: Certo, só preciso de mais uma informação. Você hospeda o seu site em um servidor fisico ou em algum servidor de cloud?

Comment: servidor convencional (cloud)

Comment: Se é em um servidor cloud, você pode utilizar um serviço hospedado pra fazer todo o deployment do seu projeto.

Segue alguns:

- Travis
- Snap-CI
- Codeship.

Cada um deles tem sua peculiaridade, eu recomendo que você leia a documentação de cada um na parte de deployments pra ver pra subir pro seu provider de cloud.

Comment: Sem querer ser chato, mas acho que você poderia colocar essas ultimas ferramentas que citou em sua resposta. Não achei ela suficientemente clara a ponto de responder a pergunta com clareza. Achei que você escreveu muito e disse pouco #soacho.

Answer (score 1):

Utilizar um servidor de integração continua, e então fazer a chamada do código do git.

Assim, configurar um pipeline que no processo final (deploy), irá mandar o código pro servidor que é o usado.

Answer (score 0):

A utilização do Git no servidor de produção não é uma boa prática! Como o @guiandmag escreveu você deve implementar um processo de deploy. Já que não é o seu fonte que deve ir para produção e sim o código binário ou final ou etc...

Uma boa referência do motivo de não usar/instalar Git em um servidor de produção: http://www.jamiembrown.com/blog/one-in-every-600-websites-has-git-exposed/